# Opt-out for Google Analytics on Android/Chrome mobile browser

Tags: browser, privacy, google-analytics

Google has an [opt-out](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/gaoptout) for Google Analytics

> To provide website visitors with the ability to prevent their data
>   from being used by Google Analytics, we have developed the Google
>   Analytics opt out browser add-on

Normally you would expect an opt-in for these kind of services, but an opt-out is something. Analytics is a program they run on my device without asking or without consent, taking CPU, battery and bandwidth and probably privacy.

But how do I opt-out on my mobile Android browser?

Comment: To be clear, Google Analytics isn't a feature of Chrome. It's not something you were opted into by using Chrome. It's not using your device's resources. It's a feature of the WEB SITES that you visit every day. It's built into THEIR code to track how their users use their site in order to improve their design. So it's actually impressive that Google has an add-on to BLOCK behavior of third-party sites that they make money off of. Nobody else does that. This doesn't answer your question, which is why I'm posting as a comment, but I wanted to clarify the perceived oddity that you pointed out.

Comment: AFAIK Analytics is a Google program/script that website-owners can embed. It is Javascript, so it is running on my device.

Comment: Well, in the same sense that any website you visit is "running on your device." But it's not a program in the sense one would typically consider it. It's no different from virtually any other component of any web page that you visit. As well, Google does work pretty hard to optimize them for speed and resource usage. My mere point was as you can't opt out of ANYTHING else on any web page, it's actually more unusual that you CAN opt out of this than expecting you to opt IN. In other words, no, you normally would NOT expect an opt-in for these kinds of services.

Comment: The amount of battery/CPU power the script consumes is infinitely smaller than the amount your screen uses while you're looking at the page. There are certainly valid reasons to want to opt-out, I think, but if your main concern is your battery I don't think this is going to have any kind of impact that could even be measured. If you're concerned about websites affecting your battery with their JS your best route would be to disable scripts entirely. In direct consideration to your question: I don't think there is an equivalent on any mobile browser.

Comment: Maybe it keeps running with my screen of. You nornally don' t exit  a mobile browser, and mostly I have more than 1 tab open.

Comment: Android suspends and sleeps most tasks while they're off-screen. Web pages, especially, are put to sleep. That's why any time I return to my browser after not long away from it, it loads the page all over again. I'm telling you, your concerns about this eating up your resources are misplaced. Every single webpage you visit has DRAMATICALLY worse offenders on it than Google Analytics. This is like trying to reduce your water usage at your water park by reducing the output of one of the bathroom faucets. The impact is nothing compared to the bigger picture.

Comment: It's eating!  Resources, energy. For sure it stuffs itself to the gullet with  my online movements. Google acknowledge that: hence the opt-out. I agree Google tends to code efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Use TrackerControl app on Fdroid store. Blocks all trackers across all your apps.

I started using Fdroid and loved it's privacy friendly no bloatware apps. You should try too